# Moment.js function causes everything after it to fail

Tags: javascript, moment-timezone

I'm trying to convert a time, 18:00 which is in United States Central time (and will change with daylight savings time) to the user's local time when they load the page.

The time to convert must be in United States central time in order to take into account daylight savings time

http://jsfiddle.net/pn9xfks4/3

```
var centTime = moment.tz("2017-10-27 18:00:00", "America/Chicago");
var localTime = moment(centTime).local();
```

Line 24-25 in the jsfiddle (pasted above) is commented out because it causes everything after it to not work.

I'm not sure if the moment code above is wrong or if something else in jsfiddle is wrong.

I'm expecting the box in the jsfiddle to say

"Monthly maintenance scheduled this Wednesday at 18:00-20:00 Central Time and HH:mm your local time" where HH:mm is local time

(I know the date isn't yet formatted for that, but I'm just trying to figure out why the date/time won't show at all for right now.

Comment: You haven't loaded moment.js but moment.locales.js. Does this work [according to your needs](http://jsfiddle.net/yh70jpg1/)?

Comment: The console says `Moment Timezone has no data for America/Chicago`. I suggest you take a look at https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @window.document for pointing that out. This was my first time using Moment.js and I did indeed forget the other library.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

I've added that and completely rewritten the script so it can be reused by anyone.

http://jsfiddle.net/y7uLtwno